# Make Calculation with a maximum (100%)

Tags: mysql, sql, data-manipulation, calculated-field

I am trying to calculate the percentage of tickets sold in MySql. However, the percentage should not exceed 100%. Is there a function for this? 
I did some research, but I cannot seem to find anything.

The code I am using is the following:

```
      ROUND((count(tickets)/capacity)*100,2)
```

Comment: CASE or IF flow control should work just fine.. something like `IF(ROUND((count(tickets)/capacity)*100,2) > 100.00, 100.00, ROUND((count(tickets)/capacity)*100,2))`

Comment: Gordon's answer is far more concise than Raymonds comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you want is `LEAST()`:

```
LEAST(ROUND((count(tickets)/capacity)*100, 2), 100.0)
```